# Can I use "guard let" if you want to pass over an optional string to "rawValue:" in enum in Swift?

Tags: swift, if-statement, enums

I want to initialize a enum from a variable of type `String?`, like:

```
guard let rawId = request.queryParameters["id"] else { 
    return
} 
guard let id = MyIdentifier(rawValue: rawId) else {
    return
}
```

In this case, `request.queryParameters["id"]` returns `String?`. Then after I ensure that it is `String` in `rawId`, I convert it into an enum instance `id`.

However, the code is dirty and I want to write it in one-line if at all possible.

However, I don't like to make it unwrapped via forced optional unwrapping, because if it can not be transformed to String, the app would end up with an error, since `rawValue:` only takes `String`. I meant something like the following, which I don't like:

```
guard let id = MyIdentifier(rawValue: request.queryParameters["id"]!) else {
    return
}
```

So is it still possible to define the `guard let` in one-line, maybe using `where` and/or `case` in `guard`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two conditions there, trying to combine them into one condition is not always possible.

In your exact case I believe an empty `id` will behave the same as a `nil` id, therefore nil coalescing can be used:

```
guard let id = MyIdentifier(rawValue: request.queryParameters["id"] ?? "") else {
    return
}
```

However, there is nothing dirty about splitting two checks into two statements. Code is not written to be short, it's written to be clear:

```
guard let rawId = request.queryParameters["id"],
      let id = MyIdentifier(rawValue: rawId) else 
   return
}
```

Also, there is nothing wrong with creating a custom initializer for your enum:

```
init?(id: String?) {
   guard let id = id else {
      return nil
   }

   self.init(rawValue: id)
}
```

and then

```
guard let id = MyIdentifier(id: request.queryParameters["id"]) else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm! I like the nil coalescing solution. And I'm pretty intrigued to see you can answer it so quickly...

Comment: @Blaszard You might be surprised to know there is a nil coalescing operator in C/Objective-C, too. E.g. `NSString *x = optionalString ?: @"default value";`. There are multiple situations when you can use it in Swift but empty string and empty array are the most typical use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can simply combine both the statements into a single statement ,i.e,

```
guard let id = request.queryParameters["id"], let id2 = MyIdentifier(rawValue: id) else { 
    return
}
```